# How to find replacement function of a mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

I wonder how I can find the replacement function of the center of the blue mass? The center of mass of the blue mass is $(0,0)$ and the blue mass is homogeneous. The masses do not move at t=0 in the system (Their initial speeds are zero). There is no friction in the system and the red mass is a point mass. $u$ is the angle of the red mass with $y$ axis.

I need help in learning the theory behind solving such systems. Thank you.

EDITED: I would like to show what I did till now to solve the problem. I followed the hints that Manishearth offered

$u=\alpha _0$
The definations of the blue mass center replacement:

$X_b(t)$ The replacement function that I try to fnd

$Y_b(t)$

The definations of the red mass Center replacement:

$X_r(t)$

$Y_r(t)$

1- Mass of center of entire system is in the beginning: 
$$r_{0x}=\frac{m. r. sin(\alpha _0)}{m+M}$$
$$r_{0y}=-\frac{m. r. cos(\alpha _0)}{m+M}$$
Mass center will not depend on time.
If So,

$$mX_r(t)+MX_b(t)=(m+M)r_{0x}=m. r. sin(\alpha _0)$$  (1)

$$mY_r(t)+MY_b(t)=(m+M)r_{0y}=-m. r. cos(\alpha _0)$$  (2)

2-Energy is conserved

$$\frac{m (\dot X_r(t))^2 } {2}+ \frac{m (\dot Y_r(t))^2 } {2}+\frac{M (\dot X_b(t))^2 } {2}+\frac{M (\dot Y_b(t))^2 } {2} +mg(a+Y_r(t))+Mg(a+Y_b(t))=mg(a-r.cos(\alpha _0))+Mga$$ (3)

I dont know how to apply Hint 3 and Hint 4.
Till now I have 4 unknown and 3 equations.
Am I in correct way to solve $X_b(t)$ ?
Thanks in advice

Comment: @Qmechanic: İt is not homework for any class. I am just self-learner in physics as engineer.(I thought the question myself because I try to learn to solving technics )  If I understand to solve such problems, I am going to clarify some points in my mind. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Have a look at the [tag description](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info). If you think that the tag does not apply, please edit it out of the question again.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for explanation. My question is for educational purpose in general.

Comment: I was a bit taken aback by the title; I though "Blue matter" was some exotic classification of matter (akin to "Dark Matter"). =D Usually titles here should be generalized to show the concept behind a homework problem, not the problem itself. I've corrected that, as well as fixed some grammar. I don't know what "first velocities" are, so I've left that statement alone.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on the meaning of "replacement function"? I think you're referring to the trick of using negative mass wile calculating center-of-mass, but I'm not sure. Google isn't helping =P

Comment: Sorry for bad grammer.Thanks for advices and help. I would like to define the the center of blue mass in time as x(t). Because of no friction, I expect a movement in blue mass after release of red mass.

Comment: Can you say a few words about your level of preparation. This could be a fairly difficult physics 101 problem or a fairly easy problem in Lagrangian mechanics (and looks chosen to highlight the advantages of using the Lagrangian approach).

Comment: I am good at electromagnetic waves , electric circuits and of course I know classical newton mechanics as electronic engineer but not so good at dynamics about rotational masses etc. I try to learn advanced mechanics that used in robotics and similiar projects.  Thanks in advice.

Comment: @dmckee: Could you please give me hint how I can apply Lagrangian approach , other classical way seems complex as you said. I can understand advanced math terms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your level of understanding of physics is, so I've broken it up into hints. If you do not understand the meaning of a hint, ask me and I'll elaborate.

Hint 1: The center of mass of the entire system should stay constant in the x-direction. This will give you a relation between the x-coordinates of the two objects. This can be differentiated to get relations between object velocities and accelerations (in x direction)

Hint 2: Energy is conserved as well.

Hint 3: Use relative velocities/accelerations; work in the frame of the blue mass.

Hint 4: There is circular motion going on in the frame of the blue body. Note that we can only apply our usual $m\omega^2 r$ formula in the moving frame of the body.